# Cards in html and css leaving behind small lines

Tags: html, css, transform

Im playing around with transform/transitions in css. I used transform:scale to enlarge a card as i hovered over it. It works, but once it returns to its regular size, it leaves behind small lines behind. In the image it can be seen on the top right, and bottom right cards. I don't know whether it is the browser or what i wrote.

Any help is appreciated[image]

```css
.card {

  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #000000;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  flex: 1 0 350px;
  min-height: 350px;
  max-width: 450px;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 1rem;

  transition:transform  600ms linear;


}

.card:hover{
  transform:scale(1.07,1.07);
```

Comment: The CSS you wrote shouldn't be causing that. Seems like an issue with the browser.

Comment: Link your website, in code you posted here isn't problem.